# Is it preferable to wash sperms before or after freezing?

Tags: fertility, sperm, sperm-count

Is it preferable to wash sperms before or after freezing? (purpose of freezing: to be used sometime in the future for insemination, undecided yet when and via which insemination method)

https://doi.org/10.1007%2Fs10815-014-0332-y says washing semen *before* freezing is preferable:

> Semen preparation by swim-up before freezing resulted in better sperm quality and fewer apoptotic sperm than sperm preparation after thawing. Therefore, sperm preparation before cryopreservation should be considered in routine sperm cryopreservation.

https://doi.org/10.1007/s10815-017-1050-z ([full text](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/pmid/28990130/)) says washing semen *after* freezing is preferable:

> Sperm preparation after freezing improves motile sperm count, motility, and viability in frozen-thawed sperm compared with sperm preparation before freezing-thawing process

Has the medical community reached a consensus now?